# How to handle pagination in Single Page Application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, pagination, single-page-application

On my Single Page Application (Javascript (AngularJs) webapp), I'm displaying a paginated items list.
I'm displaying 10 items per page.

In order to retain the current pagination opened by the user at any time while this one navigates on other page, I put the current page number on browser's localStorage. 
Here's an example of workflow:

- The user goes to `myItemsList.html`.
- He opens the page 2 involving the url: `myItemsList.html?page=2`.
- Then, he goes to another page: `myOtherPage.html`.
- He goes back to the link initially pointing to `myItemsList.html`, that displays directly thanks to localStorage the page `myItemsList.html?page=2` in order to potentially continue his navigation.

Would it confuse the user, maybe expecting to see the page 1 as a new starting navigation.
If I display at the top of the list, a kind of label like "Page 2" in order to warn him that he's seeing the preceding portion of his navigation, isn't it UX-friendly?

Or should I completely avoid persisting current pagination?

Here's what could happen if I don't persist the current viewed page:

- The user goes to `myItemsList.html`.
- He opens the page 2 involving the url: `myItemsList.html?page=2`
- He opens an item in this page (the "show" page), leading to: `myItemsList.html?id=123`
- He clicks on the browser's back button, causing a refresh of `myItemsList.html` (since a Single Page Application). The current pagination (page 2) would be lost and the user would need to restart it in order to continue its items discovery.

This seems really touchy...
What strategy should I choose for a use case like this?

Comment: Why don't you use the history api?

Comment: It could be a solution too, but many answers relative to this question mention localStorage. I am curious to know the chosen strategy with localStorage.

Comment: I'm not convinced about localStorage being useful in your scenario. I would go for URL + history api. It's a classic, proven, intuitive solution.

Comment: @Oleg I agree with you. Let's go for history API :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The URL should dictate the navigation.

When I navigate to your website, e.g. example.com, I expect to be on the first page.

When I navigate to a (bookmarked) page of your website, e.g. example.com?page=2, I expect to be on the second page.

When I hit the back button, I expect to be presented with the previous page exactly as it was when I left it. You don't need to refresh the entire page, just listen to the history events and update accordingly.

And I strongly believe that this question doesn't belong to stackoverflow...

Comment: You don't need to refresh the entire page > I expect to have the latest update even if I'm clicking on "previous". May be an item's title update, or photo etc. Could achieve this update with some technologies like websockets, but it's easier to refresh the whole.

Comment: Well, of course, if your page is some sort of "real-time" feed. But the point is that **you don't need to reload**. Just fetch a diff of the data from the server with an ajax call (especially if you're using Angular! the data binding will do the updating work for you automagically).

Comment: I agree. But when I say "reload", I do mean the actual ng-repeat section displaying the items. Not a full reload as an "F5 or Cmd+R would involve"

Answer (score 2):

saving the progress through navigation is the expected behavior in UX design of SPA, so maintaining the page he was in the correct choice, and since it is a pagination it won't be an issue even if the user wants to go back to any page, it will only take a click.

Comment: So let's imagine you go to page 4, then directly log out and close your browser. When you relaunch the web site and proceed to authentication, do you expect to display the page 4 as previously?

Comment: No, i was referring to your example. In case of logging out everything needs to be cleared from the browser cache.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just want to keep user's preferences like search filters, even if user's logs out. But the pagination data would be clear from localstorage.

Comment: then I suggest you find another way, storing such things in localstorage is not a good idea, you have to consider changing the browser, resetting it, incognito sessions, and so on.... you don't want to change the user experience if he logs out or changes the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would avoid using localstorage and use a service instead to persist ur page counter.
Secondly u dont need to persist pg counter to anywhere else but in a scope variable for refreshing to mext page data. You can even think about just adding to results similar to infinitite scroll use cases. But either way, u can use local scope variable for pagination.
Whether to go directly to last viewed page - is a more business decision and will depend on needs.

But u can very easily persist or remove persisted data using broadcast and watch and decide on persistence based on event listened to.

Hope thos helps ...

Comment: Do you mean an AngularJS "service"? If I use this, a simple refresh of the whole page (F5 on windows or Cmd+R on Mac) would lost the current page number, since Angular would completely reload its components, including this service.

Comment: I was thinking about a typical pagination scenario where page is a logical break of large resultset. However I think your's is more a "wizard" type requirement. Probably what I would do is (which will change based on real needs) have a JS object as a model ($scope var) which will drive the controls of multiple wizard pages (using ng-show, ng-f etc) which are part of single route. 
Because of browser refresh requirement, I will also persist this object in Session Storage which will be cleared by itself when user closes browser.

Answer (score 0):

How about maitaining a sort of heirerachy in JS like this :

Suppose a user navigates to a section called Customer Search

```
customer_search.customer_display.page = 2
```

*Where customer_search is the a subsection , customer_display is the view with pagination you are targetting .*

```
menu.menu_items.page=7
```

*Where menu is the subsection , menu_items is the view with pagination*

Might work if your application is organized in a reasonably hierarchical manner .

Probably you could also maintain the page in $scope for that particular controller .

Comment: Why are you reinventing the URL?

Comment: I am thinking that he is navigating to another view and the url's page number is dictated by the user input action . I am suggesting a different way using JS - I could be completely wrong though about the use case ! And its by avoiding localstorage and persisting the page counter at JS and even in the $scope . Just a though .